# Two different ATI graphics cards on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have 2 graphics cards on my computer and 4 monitors:
⠀• On ASUS 7790 3 monitors
⠀• On HIS 3650 1 monitor and it is not working

Before upgrade I had 3650 and 1650 with 2 monitors on each and they worked.

**UPGRADE:** 1650 + 3650 to 3650 + 7790

---

Now I have this view in Device Manager:
[image: Device manager current view]

How can I make it work? Updating the drivers to the latest version has not solved the problem.

Comment: Before upgrading what? When you open the properties for that device, what error(s) are listed?

Comment: Have you installed the legacy driver? http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows+7+-+64 The latest Catalyst only supports DX11 card (HD 5000 or newer)

Comment: @magicandre1981 So what drivers I need to use?

Comment: @techie007 I updated question

Comment: use the legacy driver. The normal catalyst doesn't support the older HDs any longer.

Comment: There is no legacy driver for 7790 (I mean drivers from Microsoft Update Center).